# Radon transform inversion

Tags: partial-differential-equations

**This question is for people who have access to Evan's book on PDE and are willing to do some reading.**

On page 199 (Theorem 5, Section 4.3), Evans gives us an inversion formula for the Radon transform using the fact that the Radon transform is related to the Fourier transform.

Question: is anyone else convinced that the $r^{n-1}$ in the formula (32) should really be a $|r|^{n-1}$?

I can't help but think that there's an error in the proof when Evans (essentially) claims that $\int_{-\infty}^{0}\int_{S^{n-1}}\hat{u}(r\omega)r^{n-1}e^{ir\omega\cdot x}dS dr$ is equal to $\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{S^{n-1}}\hat{u}(r\omega)r^{n-1}e^{ir\omega\cdot x}dS dr$ by "[replacing] $r$ by $-r$ and $\omega$ by $-\omega$". But under this change of variables shouldn't we conclude that the former integral is actually equal to $\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{S^{n-1}}\hat{u}(r\omega)(-r)^{n-1}e^{ir\omega\cdot x}dS dr$.

And, if I am right about this, then replacing $r^{n-1}$ by $|r|^{n-1}$ at the start of the proof allows it to go through, albeit we'll have a different conclusion than the one stated.

Comment: It looks like "If n is even" would fit in before (i) of theorem 5.  It's kind of strange that (ii) has "If n is odd" without mentioning even (I haven't looked at it especially closely though).  This would also solve your problem, since $(-1)^{n-1}$ plus the -1 from replacing $dr$ by $-dr$ would make those two integrals equal.

Comment: Along that line of logic, I'd say we'd want n odd (like in part 2) and not even. The extra -1 we get from r-->-r is, I think, absorbed in making sure the limits of integration go from 0 to infinity (and not infinity to 0). If we can agree on that point, then yes I do agree with you that that also "solves" the problem.

Comment: Ah, you're right.  I always get that mixed up.  All I can say is that it is strange then.

Comment: You are right. It seems like Evan's had a typo or something of the sort. All other sources agree on a convolution with a function which is the absolute value of "r" upon Fourier transform (i.e. Wiki and the sources therein).